# cvInRangeS simmilar in opecv 2?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering if there is something similar to `cvInRanges` in `Opencv2` which works directly on `Mat` objects.

Actually I want to convert this:

```
cvInRangeS(IplImage *m1, Scalar min, Scalar max, IplImage *m2);
```

To something like:

```
some_func (Mat m1, Scalar min, Scalar max, Mat m2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's function [`inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange). Try it.

Comment: OpenCV documentation is now hosted at http://docs.opencv.org. All OpenCV resources on willowgarage.com are deprecated and will be closed in a year.